# select row from sql where column is AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I have a laravel sql query to update a binary column here
`DB::statement("UPDATE user SET auth = AES_ENCRYPT('748b28e7c414f460607cd8', 'PASS') WHERE id = '3045948e-5521-41aa-bb76-4ad290f39053'");`
This update works.

I want to fetch the row this way, but I keep getting an empty array. Am I missing something?

`DB::select("SELECT * from user WHERE auth = aes_decrypt('748b28e7c414f460607cd8', 'PASS')");`

Basically, I want to encrypt the value that I will insert into the `auth` column and also fetch a row when I pass the decrypted value into the select statement. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: why are you using aes for what seem to be passwords?  it should only be used where you want to be able to decrypt, and you should never be able to decrypt passwords

Comment: Agreed with ysth on this one. You should never store passwords in a way that they can be decrypted. This is fine for testing/learning, but if you're storing "real" passwords as plain-text or "decyptable" strings, rethink your approach. Out of the box, Laravel provides support for [Password Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/hashing#hashing-passwords); see if you can implement that instead.

Comment: I agree with the other comments. I answered to solve the question you asked, but you should not use encryption for passwords. You should use hashing. Here's a good blog about this from Jeff Atwood: [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to query for the value you previously put in the column, then use the same function you used when you set that value.

```
SELECT * from user WHERE auth = aes_encrypt('748b28e7c414f460607cd8', 'PASS');
```

Alternatively, decrypt what you stored in the column and compare it to the same input.

```
SELECT * from user WHERE aes_decrypt(auth, 'PASS') = '748b28e7c414f460607cd8';
```

But the first example is preferred, because it can be optimized with a plain index.